# Алгоритм для подсчета количества вариантов размещения 8 пешек на шахматной доске X - Y

Tags: php, алгоритм

Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей? Это не задача про 8 ферзей которые нужно выставить на доске так чтобы они не били один другого.

Comment: Нет. Да, это точно не задача про 8 ферзей.

Comment: Это математика. Комбинаторика. X*Y - количество клеток. Так как при переставлении пешек вариант размещения не изменяется, нужна формула, которая учитывает это. Из X*Y вариантов по 8. 
Формула: (X*Y)! / (X*Y - 8 )!

Comment: @Trymount а вы не забыли тогда на 8! разделить ещё?

Comment: @pavel Да, вы правы. Требуется еще разделить на 8!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если пешки между собой не различаются имеем число сочетаний из числа допустимых полей по p=8. Если пешки по правилам не могут находиться на первой и последней горизонтали, всего полей n=48. Т.е. из 48 полей выбираем 8, на которых будут стоять пешки.

C<sub>n</sub><sup>p</sup> = n!/((n-p)!p!) = n(n-1)...(n-p+1)/p! = 377348994

```
$p= 8; $n= 48;
for($c= $n, $x= $n-1, $y= 2; $y<=$p; $y++, $x--) $c= $c*$x/$y;
echo "$c\n";
```

#### Пояснения по алгоритму.

Каждую итерацию вычисляется очередное значение C<sub>n</sub><sup>y</sup> пока y не дойдёт до p, таким образом всегда возможно деление без остатка.

Comment: Да алгоритм работает. Как объяснить эту формулу n!/((n-p)!p!) с математической точки зрения?

Comment: Число перестановок из n предметов с учетом их порядка n!. Мы берем из каждого сочетания первые p, и одни и те же из них тоже тут попадутся p! способами, поскольку нас не интересует их порядок, делим на p!. Теперь оставшиеся n-p тоже будут в разных перестановках, поскольку нам они не нужны, делим ещё на (n-p)!.